# Opengl ES 1.0 2D only last drawn texture is displayed

Tags: android, opengl-es

Setup: OpenGL ES 1.0, Android

Term **background image** here means a full screen texture which is drawn over two triangles which make the full screen rectangle.

If I draw full scene, including background image, I get black background color instead of clear color background, and I do not see my texture for background displayed

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
drawBackground();
drawParticles(scene.getNumDots());
```

Render image attached:

[image: Particles]

However, if I draw **only** the background image, I see it.

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
drawBackground();
// drawParticles(scene.getNumDots()); commented out
```

Render image attached:

[image: Render background only]

Implementations:

```
// how it was setup
public void setupGl(@NonNull final GL10 gl) {
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

// This was called
public void setDimensions(@NonNull final GL10 gl, final int width, final int height) {

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glOrthof(0, width, 0, height, 1, -1);
}

// textures were loaded like this
private void loadTexture(
        @NonNull final GL10 gl,
        @NonNull final Bitmap texture,
        final int handleOffset) {

    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, handleOffset);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[handleOffset]);

    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texture, 0);
}

private void drawBackground() {
    backgroundTextureCoordinates.position(0);
    backgroundCoordinates.position(0);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[TEXTURE_BACKGROUND]);

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_BYTE, 0, backgroundTextureCoordinates);
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_SHORT, 0, backgroundCoordinates);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

private void drawParticles(final int count) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    particlesTexturesCoordinates.position(0);
    particlesTrianglesCoordinates.position(0);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[TEXTURE_PARTICLE]);

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_BYTE, 0, particlesTexturesCoordinates);
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_SHORT, 0, particlesTrianglesCoordinates);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count * VERTICES_PER_PARTICLE);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

public void setClearColor(
        @NonNull final GL10 gl,
        @ColorInt int color) {
    gl.glClearColor(
            Color.red(color) / 255f,
            Color.green(color) / 255f,
            Color.blue(color) / 255f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: You screwed up your texture states just badly. It is totally unclear why you even need different texture units, but you basically enable texturing for unit 0 in `drawParticles` and for unit 1 in `drawBackground` (in the next frame).

Comment: @derhass, please elaborate more. I thought that I need units if I have multiple textures per handle. But if I remove both `glActiveTexture` method calls, nothing changes in the behavior.

Comment: I have no idea what you even mean by "multiple textures per handle".

Comment: @derhass I mean that the texture index array has two textures `int[] textureHandle = new int[2];` index 0 for particle and index 1 for background. Be advised that I am a noob in OpenGL, this is my first OpenGL app.

Comment: You need multiple texture units for _multitexturing_, not for having multiple textures in a program.

Comment: @darhass I need both, to have multiple textures and to have multiple textures rendered, one above the other. This is what I came up with, and I don't understand what is actually screwed up here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172317/discussion-between-yaroslav-mytkalyk-and-derhass).

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks, but either this does not produce desired results, or I put that in a wrong place. The behavior did not change.

Comment: I would also appreciate help with this https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159389/opengl-es-2-0-3-0-cannot-understand-how-to-use-2d-projection-and-shaders-with-mu

Comment: @Rabbid76, thanks. Tried using only `glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);`. Tried removing texture units at all. Nothing changed in the output, still only last drawn texture visible.

Comment: The full screen texture is coming from a file, it has no alpha channel. The texture that is above does have an alpha channel, it is generated by creating bitmap and drawing on canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way I used to draw a background

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2);
```

There, I specified the number of triangles: `2`.

Whereas I had to specify the **number of vertices** for the two triangles: `6`.

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```